# Merge rigid parts and flexible results after docking (Vina)

Tags: computational-chemistry

If I use flexible residues in the binding pocket, they are cut from the file.

The protein is broken and the amino acids are unbound in the room.

How can I get my results and the protein together again?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Useful Script for AutoDock4 and Vina That Merges Flexible and Rigid PDBQT Output
« Prosciens.
http://prosciens.com/prosciens/a-useful-script-for-autodock4-and-vina-that-
merges-flexible-and-rigid-pdbqt-output/
Link to the script: http://prosciens.com/prosciens/oldproscienssarl/files/flexrigidpdbqt2pdb_template.sh